# Fragments in GingerBread

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am writing an app for android which uses Fragments, but when I run the application on a GingerBread phone, I get an error in this line:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
```

which says

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

everything is supposedly good, the MainActivity extends FragmentActivity, The ViewPager, the FragmentPagerAdapter and the Fragment are all from the support package. so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the layout file that contains the line #8 that the error is complaining about.

Comment: Check your LINT warnings

Comment: God i feel so stupid... apparently gingerbread doesnt like it when you put a String as the textColor...

Comment: @CommonsWare you were the one the got me looking at the XML file so post an answer so I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

On the left screen of Eclipse:

click your project then click "libs" 
You will see the libraries that you were used on your project. 
Right click the "android-support-v4.jar" select the "Build Path" / "Add to Build Path"

After do this, 
top of the your activity delete the import things that about the FRAGMENTS.

use v4.app.Fragment

now try it again?

Comment: @oriwass : As Commonsware commented on your question. Post the layout file - the problem is on line 8 of that file.

Comment: i suggest that : Not use <Fragment..> in your layout file. If you wanna be have more power on fragments, you have to use programmatically fragments. For example use <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/my_fragment_area" ... />  then you will fill this layout with your fragment that whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

as others have mentioned, Fragments aren't supported on pre-honeycomb versions of Android, so you will need to use a library for this.

Google has one, and there is also a very popular library called [**ActionBarSherlock**](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) , which also has examples of how to use them.

i think the best way to learn how to use them is read the samples code. it's not so hard.

Answer (score -1):

`Fragment` is introduced in `API level 11 (Honeycomb)`. So if you want to use `Fragments` flexibly in below `AIP level 11` you should use library like `ABS (ActionBarSherlock)` you can get it from github(https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock). Better use that.

Comment: *Technically*, you don't need ActionBarSherlock to use fragments in Gingerbread, you just need the Android compatibility library.

Comment: if you want to use Fragments flexibly in below AIP level 11 you should use library like ABS (ActionBarSherlock)